# How to rotate an element/framework element?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I feel like this should be really easy, but I can't rotate an element about a point.

I can set the position of the point without any fuss at all, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way rotate it.

```
    private void SetPosition(FrameworkElement element, ColorImagePoint point)
    {
        //Divid width and height by 2 to centre
        Canvas.SetLeft(element, point.X - element.Width / 2); //X axis
        Canvas.SetTop(element, point.Y - element.Height / 2); //Y axis
        //I want to do something like this here:
        Canvas.SetRotate(element, about_this_point, by_this_angle)
    }
```

On my canvas in the image properties there's an option to rotate it, but I can't figure out how to do it in code so that it can be done dynamically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a simple example XAML rotation.

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{StaticResource  Image_Key}" >
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX="50" CenterY="50" Angle="45" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

this simply apply a rotation based on 50,50  point in the image. as the size is set to 100 x 100 this mean it's a center rotation. You can easily bind all these value with your model.

So adding from there the format is define but to add in code is simple :

```
RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform(); 
myRotateTransform.Angle = 45; 
myImage.RenderTransform = myRotateTransform;
```

or if you need more than only rotation create a `TransformGroup` object, add the different tranformation to it with `TransformGroup.Children.Add([transformation]);` and set the `RenderTransform` to the `TransformGroup` instead and voila